# How to Install PHP 8.1 on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to install PHP 8.1 on my Ubuntu Server, but I'm encountering difficulties. I followed the standard procedure, adding the Ondřej Surý PPA, but I can't seem to find the PHP 8.1 package.

I've updated my system and executed the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php8.1
```

I expected the installation to proceed smoothly. Can someone guide me on how to install PHP 8.1 on Ubuntu Server 18.04 or suggest an alternative method?

Comment: 18.04 is end of life, so I believe the maintainer of the PPA you're referring to removed any packages targeted at that version of Ubuntu (presumably because they didn't want the overhead of supporting packages for an unsupported version of Ubuntu). Time to upgrade.

Comment: Consider upgrading the server. `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: _"Only [Supported Versions of PHP](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for [Supported Ubuntu Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided."_

Comment: Thankyou for your support upgrading my ubuntu version solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to use`sudo -i` if you wont to not type`sudo` and your password every time and to do it you need.

```
 apt update
 apt upgrade
 apt install php
 apt update
 apt upgrade
```

That will install automatically the newest version of php or "php8.1".
And if wona know the path of `php.ini` for configurating php in apache2 service is in  /etc/php/8.1/apache2/